# Angular ng-show not working to display an image after processing

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

```
        $scope.getGraph = function(hash) {
        if ($scope.clickedFile.hash == hash) return;

        $scope.graph = "";
        $scope.pictureLoaded = false;
        $scope.loadingPic = true;

        if (hash) {
            $http({
                method: "GET",
                url: $rootScope.baseUrl+"api/file/" + hash + '?graph' ,
            }).then(function mySucces(response) {
                $scope.graph = response.data;
                $scope.pictureLoaded = true;
                $scope.loadingPic = false;
                console.log('picture loaded')

            }, function myError(response) {
               //handling errors
            });
        }

    }
```

This function is called at some point when a user click on a file. The goal is to do some processing and show a loading bar. At some point the image is processed and therefore I set loadingPicture to true.
At this moment I want the picture to replace the loading bar

```
<img ng-src="data:image/png;base64,{{graph}}" ng-show="pictureLoaded" style="width:40%; height:40%; display:block;margin: 0 auto;"/>
```

But instead it just show nothing.
I tried to use $scope.apply but then I get an error saying a digest is already in progress. 
So I've tried to put that .apply inside

```
 if(!$scope.$$phase) {
 //$digest or $apply}
```

But that doesn't work either : (

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure the image path is correct ?

Comment: There is no path it's `ng-src="data:image/png;base64,{{graph}}"`and I'm sure the data is correct. If I leave this page and come back the image is displayed. But I need it to be displayed on the page right away

Comment: Just to exclude simple errors: Are you sure `mySuccess` gets called and `$scope.pictureLoaded` is written to the *correct* scope?

Comment: Yes, because as I said in my previous comment if I go on another page and come back then the image is displayed

Comment: Maybe a cache problem ? for example if you upload a new image but the link stay the same, it will not be updated. You have to add a timestamp (or a random number) in a param to the source of the image

Comment: Try adding $scope.graph + "?ts=" + new Date().getTime();" everytime you update the image

Answer (score 0):

Use **$timeout** instead.
For Example:

```
 $timeout(()=>{
   $scope.$apply();  
 }, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be a cache problem.

I don't know what exactly is the content of the response.data, but if it's the same graph than it was before, the image will not be refreshed unless your timestamp it.

You can try to add :

```
$scope.graph = $scope.graph + "?ts=" + new Date().getTime();
```

The, the image will refresh every time it's updated, even if the graph content is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Ok well my bad. The data was not b64 encode from the frontend. For some reason it still displayed if we changed page.
Thank you